# Java creating a custom Map

Tags: java, dictionary

I have two questions regarding my following code:

1) Is there any way I can `implement Map` in this case, rather than extend just one direct implementation of the interface? I do not wish to write a whole Map implementation though. But it could be nice seeing that my implementation does not care what underlying Map implementation is being used.
2) Are there any bad practices?

ExtremesMap.java

```
package ocr.util;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 *
 * @author student
 */
public class ExtremesMap extends HashMap<String, Integer> {
    private Set<String> smallest;
    private int smallestValue;

    private Set<String> biggest;
    private int biggestValue;

    public ExtremesMap() {
        super();
        smallest = new HashSet<>();
        smallestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        biggest = new HashSet<>();
        biggestValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public void put(String key, Integer value) {
        if (value == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ocr.util.ExtremesMap.put: value == null");
        }
        //TODO for real performance application implement own type of Map directly
        Integer retrieveValue = super.get(key);
        if (retrieveValue != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ocr.util.ExtremesMap.put: Not allowed to modify existing value: key = " + key);
        }
        else if (retrieveValue == value) {
            return;
        }
        super.put(key, value);
        if (value < smallestValue) {
            smallest = new HashSet<>();
            smallestValue = value;
        }
        else if (value == smallestValue) {
            smallest.add(key);
        }
        if (value > biggestValue) {
            biggest = new HashSet<>();
            biggestValue = value;
        }
        else if (value == biggestValue) {
            biggest.add(key);
        }
    }

    public String getSmallestString() {
        if (smallest.size() != 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ocr.util.ExtremesMap.getSmallest: smallest.size() != 1: smallest.size() = " + smallest.size());
        }
        return smallest.iterator().next();
    }

    public Set<String> getSmallestSet() {
        return smallest;
    }

    public List<String> getSmallestList() {
        return Arrays.asList(getSmallestArray());
    }

    public String[] getSmallestArray() {
        return smallest.toArray(new String[smallest.size()]);
    }

    public String getBiggestString() {
        if (biggest.size() != 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ocr.util.ExtremesMap.getBiggest: biggest.size() != 1: biggest.size() = " + biggest.size());
        }
        return biggest.iterator().next();
    }

    public Set<String> getBiggestSet() {
        return biggest;
    }

    public List<String> getBiggestList() {
        return Arrays.asList(getBiggestArray());
    }

    public String[] getBiggestArray() {
        return biggest.toArray(new String[biggest.size()]);
    }
}
```

Also there is one bug which I am unable to resolve in `put()`:

method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

```
put(String,Integer) in ExtremesMap cannot implement put(K,V) in Map
  return type void is not compatible with Integer
  where K,V are type-variables:
    K extends Object declared in interface Map
    V extends Object declared in interface Map
```

What exactly goes wrong here?

Regards.

Comment: ``AbstractMap`` provides typical map functionality (see JavaDoc). For your ``put`` method, it has to return an ``Integer``, as the error clearly states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, the [`put` signature is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29):

```
 V put(K key, V value)
```

That means that your method `put` should return `Integer` and not `void`:

```
public Integer put(String key, Integer value) { ... }
```

Concerning your first two questions, I would say that it is not a recommended practice to extend `HashMap`, because you are changing the way a Map is working when you override `put`. You should better use composition instead (a normal class which contains a private field `Map` for internal use).

For a whole code review of your code, you could ask at [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).